# Why We need Left-Multiplication Matrix Separately

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

In Friedberg, Ingel, and Spence Linear Algebra (4th Edition), defined left-multiplication transformation as the following:

> Let $A$ be an $m × n$ matrix with entries from a field F. We denote by
> $L_A$ the mapping $L_A: F^n \rightarrow F^m $ defined by $L_A(x) = Ax$
> (the matrix product of $A$ and $x$) for each column vector $x$
> $\epsilon$ $F^n$. We call $L_A$ a $\mathbf{\text{left-multiplication transformation}}$.

The answers [here][1] and [here][2] tries to explain left-multiplication transformation.

My question is:

i) If someone can explain this definition in more layman terms? For some reason this definition is not very clear to me and the 2 links also didn't help much.

ii) Why we need a new definition of left-transformation matrix for $\mathbb{R}$? We already proved "all" linear transformation can be associated with a matrix, say $A$, if ordered basis can be defined. So, I can't find the utility of new definition.

iii) From the definition it seems linear map is "contingent" on $A$ ($A$ is defined independent of linear map), what's guarantee that dimension of matrix associated with linear map, $[T]_\beta^\gamma$, defined on $\mathbb{R}$ and dimension of $A$ will be same?

Thanks!
[1]: [What exactly is a left-multiplication transformation?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2738278/what-exactly-is-a-left-multiplication-transformation)
[2]: [Linear Transformations and Left-multiplication Matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3252146/linear-transformations-and-left-multiplication-matrix)

Comment: What do you mean by the “dimension of a linear map” and the “dimension of $A$”? Those expressions don’t make sense.

Comment: @littleO: Let $T: V \rightarrow W$ be a linear map and $\beta$ and $\gamma$ be ordered basis of vector space respectively. Then $[T]_\beta^\gamma$ I'm saying as "dimension of a linear map".

Comment: That also doesn't seem to make sense. $[T]_\beta^\gamma$ is a matrix. Why would you call it the "dimension" of a linear map? Dimension is not the correct word.

Comment: @littleO: I updated my question based on your suggestion. Hopefully this time my question is more accurate. Thanks!

Comment: That's an improvement. It's still unclear what you mean by the "dimension" of a matrix. Do you mean the shape of the matrix? What is the "dimension" of the matrix $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3 \\ 4 & 5 & 6 \end{bmatrix}$, for example? See the comments [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2170009/40119). "A matrix has no 'dimension'. It has a 'size'." (I prefer the term "shape", personally.)

Comment: @littleO: Yes. So, say $A's$ dimention is $k \times l$ and matrix associated with linear map $T$  , $[T]_\beta^\gamma$ dimension is $m \times n$. Why $k = m$ and $l = n$? This is  the best way I can simplify my question. Thanks!

Comment: Essentially, left versus right multiplication boils down to whether the linear transformation $AB$ means "First apply $A$, then $B$" (right multiplication, because it would be natural to write $xAB$) or "First apply $B$ then $A$" (left multiplication, because then it would be natural to write $ABx$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this [old answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3177868/why-linear-maps-act-like-matrix-multiplication/3177904#3177904) of mine, the diagram in particular. This should hopefully be something familiar to you.

The idea is that we wish to describe transformations from abstract $n$-dimensional space $V$, to abstract $m$-dimensional space $W$, in more familiar, computable terms. If we fix a basis $\beta$ for $V$, this gives us an isomorphism between $V$ and the space $F^n$, which takes abstract vectors $v \in V$, and transforms it into the column vector $[v]_\beta \in F^n$. This turns the mysterious, abstract, possibly difficult to work with space $V$ into a familiar space of column vectors. Addition in $V$ corresponds to adding these column vectors, and similarly for scalar multiplication. We can completely understand $V$, by looking at only coordinate vectors instead.

Similarly, fixing a basis $\gamma$ for $W$ similarly gives us an isomorphism $w \mapsto [w]_\gamma$ from $W$ to $F^m$. In much the same way, we can understand the abstract vector space $W$ concretely in terms of column vectors.

This also means that linear transformations from $V$ to $W$, which again can be quite abstract, can be concretely understood as linear transformations between $F^n$ and $F^m$ (once bases $\beta$ and $\gamma$ are fixed).

The nice thing is that linear transformations between $F^n$ and $F^m$ can be expressed as multiplication by unique $m \times n$ matrices. This is what this definition is trying to establish. This step is important: we need not only to establish a correspondence between linear maps $T : V \to W$ and linear maps $S : F^n \to F^m$, but between linear maps $T : V \to W$ and $m \times n$ matrices. Both connections are important to establish this.

There needs to be two directions to this: we need to show that a linear map from $F^n$ to $F^m$ can be expressed as multiplication by an $m \times n$ matrix, and that multiplication by an $m \times n$ matrix is always a linear map from $F^n$ to $F^m$. The latter is what is about to be established. Without showing that $L_A : F^n \to F^m$ is linear, then all we know is that linear maps between $V$ and $W$ correspond to **some** $m \times n$ matrices. What if certain $m \times n$ matrices turn out to be out-of-bounds?

They're not. As it turns out, $L_A$ is linear, just by standard distributivity and associativity properties of matrices, e.g.
$$L_A(x + y) = A(x + y) = Ax + Ay = L_A(x) + L_A(y).$$
This and the scalar homogeneity argument imply that $L_A$ is always a linear map.

Here is an example to show you how this definition works. Suppose we pick arbitrarily  a matrix like
$$A = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & -1 \\ 0 & 0 \\ 2 & -2\end{pmatrix}.$$
Then, $A$ is $3 \times 2$, and so $L_A$ should be a linear map from $\Bbb{R}^2$ to $\Bbb{R}^3$. By definition,
$$L_A\begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & -1 \\ 0 & 0 \\ 2 & -2\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} x - y \\ 0 \\ 2x - 2y\end{pmatrix}.$$
Hopefully you can see that this is a linear transformation, and if you were to take the standard matrix for this linear transformtion, you would simply get $A$. You can do this with any $A$, helping prove that matrix multiplication is equivalent to general linear transformations between finite-dimensional spaces.

Comment: Thanks for your brilliant answer! This is very useful. But there are couple of statement here that I didn't understand. i) "If we fix a basis $\beta$ for $V$, this gives us an isomorphism between $V$ and the space $F^n$. $F$ is a field, say real-numbers, and if $V$ is vector space of polynomials. Then how fixing basis establish relation between $V$ and $F^n$?

Comment: ii) "we need not only to establish a correspondence between linear maps $T:V \rightarrow W$ and linear maps $S:F^n \rightarrow F^m$, but between linear maps $T:V \rightarrow W$ and $m \times n$ matrices": We already established relationship between $T$ and matrix representation $m \times n$. So, why we need to establish it?

Comment: Where we "establish a correspondence between linear maps $T:V \rightarrow W$ and linear maps $S:F^n \rightarrow F^m$" in this definition? Sorry too many questions! But thanks a lot again!

Comment: @Beta Regarding your first question, we establish a relation by way of coordinate vectors. If you fixed the ordered basis $(x, 1, x^2)$ for $P_2(\Bbb{R})$ (yes, I chose a bad order just to be annoying!), then this yields a map taking $ax^2 + bx + c$ to its column vector $\begin{pmatrix} b \\ c \\ a\end{pmatrix}$. This map is an isomorphism, meaning that it is linear and invertible, so it respects addition and scalar multiplication, as does its inverse. Choosing a different basis will produce a difference correspondence. By fixing a basis, we can understand $P_2(\Bbb{R})$ as $\Bbb{R}^3$.

Comment: Perfect!!! Thanks a ton!

Comment: ii) That's kind of skipping a step. If we understand $V$ as $F^n$ and $W$ as $F^m$, then we can naturally understand $T : V \to W$ as a map from $F^n$ to $F^m$. These linear maps can be understood as matrix multiplication. I find it useful to make this distinction, because there are *many* ways to go from $V$ and $W$ to $F^n$ and $F^m$, but only *one* way to make a map $F^n \to F^m$ into a matrix. Plus the methods for stepping from abstract linear map to concrete linear map is quite different from stepping from concrete linear map to matrix.

Comment: Thanks! This  make sense too now.

Comment: Do you still want me to answer (iii)? I can, but I think if you understand the other two, your doubts about (iii) should be clearing now.

Comment: no :). It's perfectly clear now. Thank you Theo for clearing my doubts. I was struggling with it for quite sometime.